# Why is the value of my radio inputs NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

So I have a piece of code

```
$(this).find('input[name^="radio-qid-"]:checked').val()
```

where `$(this)` contains a piece of HTML like gets the checked radio button in a piece of HTML like

```
<div class="yesno-holder">
   <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" class="yes-radio" name="radio-qid-2" value="100" checked="">Yes</label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" class="no-radio" name="radio-qid-2" value="50">No</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

and what's strange is that it's always calculating as `NaN` in that context, whereas if I type in `$('input[name^="radio-qid-"]:checked').val()` to the browser, which gets all checked radio buttons in such pieces of HTML, it prints out a real value (as a string). So what is going on here????

Comment: What do you *do* with the result of that jQuery expression? How do you know it's `NaN`? You really haven't posted enough code; as you noted, that expression does work.

Comment: True. In fact is difficult to find the "problem".

Comment: So where are you using the value that is returning NaN?

Answer (score 2):

The value returned from a form will be a string. You have to convert it to a number first.

Try taking the value you get from the radio button and putting it through `parseInt` e.g. `parseInt($('input[name^="radio-qid-"]:checked').val(),10)`

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a more specific reason why the "this" selector isn't working.

The "this" selector refers that whatever the value is within a parent element. For example, try using this code and it will function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.yesno-holder').click(function(){
        var value = ($(this).find('input[name^="radio-qid-"]:checked').val());
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

In this instance, this refers to content that is within the '.yesno-holder' that was clicked. You could set up as many '.yesno-holder' instances as you like and it will only return the results within the class you click.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... i've tested and all is workin' fine here...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name^="radio-qid-"]:checked').on('change',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="yesno-holder">
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" class="yes-radio" name="radio-qid-2" value="100" checked="">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" class="no-radio" name="radio-qid-2" value="50">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```